# Power set cardinality exercise, where am I wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Exercise. Find the cardinality.
$|P(P(P(A\times\varnothing)))|$

My solution 1:

$|P(P(P(A\times\varnothing)))|=2^{|P(P(A\times\varnothing))|}=2^{2^{|P(A\times \varnothing)|}}=2^{2^{2^{|A\times\varnothing|}}}=2^{2^{2^{|\varnothing|}}}= 2^{2^{2^0}}=2^2=4$

My solution 2:

$|P(P(P(A\times\varnothing)))|=|P(P(P(\varnothing)))|=|P(P(\{\varnothing \}))|=|P(\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\} \})|=|\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\} \}, \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\} \}    \}|=4$

But I got it wrong in my homework. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Both solutions look right to me.  Is there an answer key with a different solution, or have you asked your teacher what's wrong with your answer?

Comment: No, it was homework but I wanted to be sure before asking the teacher. Maybe it was a mistake somewhere.

Comment: This also seems correct to me. I know this sounds silly but can you double-check you read the question properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct. I suspect that in the question "$\emptyset$" may have been a typo (or miscopied) for "$\{\emptyset\}$," in which case the answer would be $2^{2^{2^{\vert A\vert}}}$ instead of $4$. (There's also the sad possibility that the claimed correct answer is $0$, which is what one gets if one forgets that $\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}\not=\emptyset$.)